# Is it possible to convert from Geography to Geometry in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I have a shp file that has geography types, Can I convert it with a tool like shp2pgsql? or  is there a postgis function to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be able to use shp2pgsql direct from the command line though I am unsure on syntax off-hand...we've done this in my existing environment, though someone else wrote that and I'm not sure.

There are also GIS tools that can assist with this...  http://www.safe.com/  is a 3rd party program that gives another route.

Some ETL tools such as Pentaho seem to be quite capable of doing this as well.

Comment: It looks like I had a different projection, I only had to transform, but you're right with shp2psql you can directly transform to geometry type.